# Is there any way to use a button sender to send the text (on a button) directly into a listbox

Tags: c#

i have tried 2 solutions but neither of them work, the first on is to directly send it into the listbox but neither of them work

1.To send it directly into the listbox

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Button b = (Button)sender;
               lbItems = b.Text;
    }
```

2.The other method i tried was to send it into a a texbox first then send the the string from the texbox into the listbox, but the code breks after one button

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Button b = (Button)sender;
           lbItems = b.Text;

      if (txtPre.Text == " ")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            lbItems.Items.Add(txtPre.Text);
            txtPre.Clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `lbItems.Items.Add(b.Text);`?

Comment: `lbItems = b.Text;` is illegal code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lbItems.Items.Add((sender as Button).Text);
```